# GPSD giving mode 0 in libgpsmm

Tags: c++, gps, raspberry-pi, gpsd

I'm trying to use the C++ integration with GPSD on a Pi.  If I run GPSMON I can verify that I have a full fix without issue, however in my C++ program I am getting a fix with mode 0, which means "MODE UPDATE NOT SEEN YET".

The program isn't erroring out at the socket connection, so I'm not sure what's causing the disconnect.

Comment: What would you get if you queried `?DEVICES;` or `?VERSION;`?

Comment: Do you remember if you ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using libgps and libgpsmm. Your problem may be caused by a version incompatibility between gpsd daemon and libgps.
I.e. the client (libgps) may speak a different version of the "API protocol" [gpsd_json](http://catb.org/gpsd/gpsd_json.html) than the gpsd daemon.
This may happen if you decided to build/link a static version of libgps -- which does not *exactly* match the version number of gpsd. Or if your client runs on a diffent machine than gpsd server.

I ran into same problem and it took me valuable time to figure out the reason:
JSON parser in libgps is designed badly. It ignores/discards JSON objects which contain name/value pairs, which are not known a priori.
So whole TPV messages from gpsd may be discarded and your client implementation shows no error message, neither libgps functions return an error code. Too bad.

Here it is ([json.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gpsd.git/tree/json.c), line 296+, @2016-07-27):

> ```
>   if (cursor->attribute == NULL) {
>       json_debug_trace((1,
>                 "Unknown attribute name '%s' (attributes begin with '%s').\n",
>                 attrbuf, attrs->attribute));
>       /* don't update end here, leave at attribute start */
>       return JSON_ERR_BADATTR;
>   }
> ```

And here ([libgps_json.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gpsd.git/tree/libgps_json.c), line 27+, @2016-07-27):

> ```
> static int json_tpv_read(const char *buf, struct gps_data_t *gpsdata, const char **endptr)
> {
>     const struct json_attr_t json_attrs_1[] = {
>       {"class",  t_check,   .dflt.check = "TPV"},
>       {"device", t_string,  .addr.string = gpsdata->dev.path, .len = sizeof(gpsdata->dev.path)},
>       {"time",   t_time,    .addr.real = &gpsdata->fix.time, .dflt.real = NAN},
>       ...
> ```

Use `_gpsmm->enable_debug( level, stderr )` with `level>=6` and compile libgps, libgpsmm with `define CLIENTDEBUG_ENABLE` to get the debug trace output.

git repositiory of gpsd sources tells us dates of recent incompatible changes on the gpsd_json protocol:

> git commits:
>   2016-04-07  Add "status" to TPV for DGPS notification
>   2016-01-04  Address Savannah bug #46804: JSON satellite view parsing is somewhat broken.
>   2015-04-04  Add client-library parsing of PPS precision.
>   2015-01-24  In client library, "dip" member was missing from ATT parsing.
>   Releases:
>   3.11  23-Aug-2014
>   3.12  22-Feb-2015  *incompatible*
>  
>   3.13  26-Feb-2015
>   3.14  14-Mar-2015
>   3.15  03-Jun-2015  *incompatible*
>   3.16  08-Jan-2016  *incompatible*
>   3.17  xx-xxx-xxxx  *incompatible*

Do gpsd developers not care about client-server compatibility across versions? What about shared libgps library binary API/ABI stability then?
It is missing versioning functions. Very unsafe also.
(Look at the comment git comment on the 2015-04-04 change mentioned above: *Data is currently discarded, pending the next gps_data_t structure break.*)